# How to get a String from a Lazy.Builder?

Tags: haskell, bytestring

I need to manipulate the binary encoding as `'0'` and `'1'` of simple strings given as input, using ascii 7-bits.

For the encoding I have used the function `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Builder.string7 :: String -> Builder`

However, I have not found a way to convert back the resulting Builder object into a string of `'0'` and `'1'`. Is it possible ? Is there another way ?

Subsidiary question: And if I wanted it in hexadecimal form as text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an `unpackChars` function in `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal`. There's also a non-lazy counterpart in `Data.ByteString.Internal`.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Builder as Build
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal as BSI

--> BSI.unpackChars $ Build.toLazyByteString $ Build.string7 "010101"
--"010101"
```

You can also use `map (chr . fromIntegral) . BS.unpack` instead of `unpackChars`, but `unpackChars` is probably faster.

Alternatively, as Michael Snoyman commented below, you could use `Data.ByteString.Char8` or its lazy version and you'll get the right conversions to begin with.

Comment: I'd recommend using [Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8.unpack](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.1/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy-Char8.html#v:unpack) instead.